# Error resolving version for plugin spring-boot-maven-plugin'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

getting below error in eclipse while importing maven project and trying to update it...
Error resolving version for plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\tBuild\repo), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhOI.png)

Answer (score 2):

In general you should share your `pom.xml` to get the the correct answer otherwise we can only speculate.

Here are some of the possible reasons:

1. You haven't specified the spring boot maven plugin version, at least raises a warning about it.
2. This can be resolved automatically if you inherit from spring boot parent or use bill of materials. These require additional declarations in your pom. For parent (usual approach) it should be something like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>    
</parent>
```

Comment: I have mentioned the parent

Comment: parent dependency from our project related which i gues internally uses above parent which you mentioned

Comment: below maven plugin is mentioned in our pom file.
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

Comment: also maven project layout not populated properly eventhough i'm importing project as a maven project

Comment: Well, again without the pom the community can only speculate... Is it possible to share the pom? Do you have actual spring boot dependencies (like starters, etc) do they get resolved without version correctly?

Comment: How can i attach complete pom file here....stack overflow saying some number of character validation?

Comment: yes i have actual spring boot dependencies like
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: You can update the question, just paste the content of the pom into the question. You can use triple tilde (~) for specifying starting an ending of your pom. Welcome to SO BTW, I should have told you that at the very beginning :)

Comment: ok just updating question ....to answer your above question that spring boot starter dependencies working fine without mentioning version...i can see they got downloaded in my local maven repo
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Also along with this issue i am facing problem of below certification error when i tried to clean install or update maven project
Description Resource Path Location Type
unable to find valid certification path to requested target pom.xml /demo line 1 Maven pom Loading Problem

Comment: and my maven project structure layout not populating correctly even though i'm importing project as a maven project...you can comment on these too please